# Ad-hoc (WiFi or bluetooth) in flash-app on Android

Tags: android, flash, adhoc, multiplayer

Would it be possible to create an ad-hoc multiplayer connection (close range) between two or several phones in a flash application?

Answer (score 0):

Flash won't let you communicate directly to another machine. You need a server to handle communications between clients.

Comment: Maybe this would help?
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/06/androideroids.html out. It's a multiplayer flash-app between several phones on Android. I'm not sure about the implementation but it looks like you still need a host like Byron stated.